# Maximum Voltage Input and output current for transistor pnp and npn

Tags: transistors, maximum-ratings

How can I know the maximum voltage input for transistor. I look at datasheet. But confusing me little bit. Which is for maximum voltage. Afraid that might burn the transistor. Btw, my input circuit is 48V and current needed is 30mA. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vceo for general purpose requirements.

That kind of 8050-type transistor is optimized for lower voltages.

If you actually need to switch the 48V at low current, then a 160V MMBT5551 is a reasonable low-cost and multiple-sourced choice.

If your input is 48V and you are switching lower voltage than 25V (minus a safety margin) then the one you’ve shown will work, but as always, you will need a base resistor to limit the current since the Vbe will be about 0.7V when on (and applying much more than that will destroy the transistor).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that matters is collector-emitter voltage (Vceo). This is listed at 25V. You will need a different transistor to work with 48V.

Emitter-base voltage won’t be much more than 0.7V normally.